# Como eu carrego um controller dentro de outro?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Bem, minha duvida é como eu carrego um controlador/método dentro de outro controlador, no CodeIgniter 2.2.2

```
<?php if(! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Inicio extends CI_Controller {
   public function index(){
      $this->load->library('controllers/Desenvolvedor/Desenvolvedor');
   }
}
//Esse é o controlador principal.
```

[image: print]

Comment: Tipo assim, eu tenho 1 controlador principal, e através dele eu quero "pedir" um outro controlador que tá dentro de uma pasta, no caso , Controllers/Desenvolvedor/Desenvolvedor.php (desenvolvedor o primeiro é a pasta e a segunda é o nome do controlador que é igual a pasta);

Comment: Recomendo que você pode [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/55662/edit) sua pergunta, e adicionar estas informações complementares do comentário, ao corpo da pergunta, tornando a pergunta melhor e mais clara. E se possível até forneça mais detalhes do que você deseja fazer, tornando mais clara a quem puder lhe ajudar.

Comment: Pelo código, me parece que seja bem ruim fazer assim, porque abrir um `Library` dentro da pasta `Controller`, não carrega `controller` dentro de outro `controller`, quem sabe contando o que deseja solucionar, ou seja, qual é o seu problema?

Comment: O nome disso é _POG_. Pode até funcionar, mas é má prática (penso). Quando vc chega ao ponto de precisar carregar um _controller_ dentro do outro é hora de pensar mais em usar uma biblioteca, ou um [_helper_](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/index.html). Isso é, se o _controller_ vai abrigar uma função que deve ser acessada por outros _controllers_, então o que vc precisa é de uma biblioteca, ou de um [_helper_](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/index.html). No MVC, a função do _controller_ é responder requisições intermediando _model_ e _view_, e não servir dados.

Answer (score 2):

Dando uma pesquisada, além de chamar por library, você pode estender sua classe filha (ex: inicio.php) à classe pai (ex: desenvolvedor.php), permitindo as chamadas de função no controller

```
//desenvolvedor.php
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Desenvolvedor extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct()
    }
    public function meuMetodo($algo){
        echo $algo;
    }
}


//inicio.php
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Inicio extends Desenvolvedor{
    public funcion inicio(){
        $this->meuMetodo('faça algo');
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeu gurizão! Obrigado pela ajuda hehe

Comment: Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como [aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/6603). Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 1):

Bom amigo se eu entendi direito, isso é simples de fazer.
Eu imaginei a seguinte situação: que você tem o controller Desenvolvedor.php que fica em controllers/Desenvolvedor/Desenvolvedor.php ai você tem outro controller chamado Frontend.php que fica em controllers/Frontend/Frontend.php ai você precisa utilizar controller Desenvolvedor.php dentro do controller Frontend.php então dentro do controller Frontend.php você vai carregar o seu controller Desenvolvedor.php dessa forma:

```
$this->load->library('controllers/Desenvolvedor/Desenvolvedor');
```

Comment: Era bem essa a minha duvida, mas não ta funcionando, no caso acontece isso aqui : 
"
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: desenvolvedor
"

Comment: Já conferi as coisas... Não vi erro nenhum em sintaxe...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/GwbWxfS.png Aqui ta "a foto" de diretorios

Comment: O arquivo inicio.php está dentro da pasta "controllers" então você chamará da seguinte forma $this->load->library('Desenvolvedor/Desenvolvedor');

Answer (score 1):

Cheguei até este tópico com a mesma dúvida. Porém nenhuma destas alternativas funcionaram no Code Igniter 3.1.6, pode ser que tenha feito algo errado.
Mas achei uma solução bem simples e que resolveu meu problema.

```
redirect('/NomeController');
```

Após uma inserção no banco de dados eu utilizei para chamar o meu controller.